# Configuring Dell touchpad to fix jumpy cursor

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, dell, synaptics, input-devices

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on a dell inspiron touch screen module. Wheever I type my touchpad jumps. I have tried an array of guides on this forum but nothing worked well for me.

```
$xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0743:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$xinput list-props 12
Device 'DELL0743:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (139):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (265): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (289):  49, 1180, 50, 879
Synaptics Finger (290): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (291):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (292):   67
Synaptics Tap Durations (293):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (294):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (295):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (296):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (297):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (298): -30, -30
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (299): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (300):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (301): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.129870, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (302):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (303):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (304):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (305): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Click Action (306):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (307): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (308):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (309): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (310):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (311): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (312):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (313): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (314):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (315): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (316):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (317):  0
Synaptics Gestures (318):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (319):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (320): 12, 12
Synaptics Area (321):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (322):  614, 0, 761, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (323): 7, 7
Device Product ID (257):    1739, 32402
Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event12"
```

Following is the synclient -l output

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1585
    RightEdge               = 5357
    TopEdge                 = 1446
    BottomEdge              = 4408
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 245
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = -111
    HorizScrollDelta        = -111
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0358744
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 0
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 27
    VertHysteresis          = 27
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3471
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 4028
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop and was having the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04, I installed Touchpad Indicator which allows you to disable the touchpad while typing and other tweaks.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install touchpad-indicator`

For more info you can see this post here: https://websetnet.com/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-16-04/